# Prove that the isotopy generated by a time-dependent symplectic vector field is a symplectomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, exterior-algebra

Let $M$ a compact and connected smooth manifold.
Suppose $X_t$ is a time-dependent symplectic vector field and let $\phi_t$ be the isotopy generated by $X_t$. Prove that $\phi_t ∈ Symp(M, \omega)$ for all $t$.

**I know that**:

Given a symplectic form $\omega$ on $M$, we denote by $Symp(M, \omega)$ the space of symplectomorphisms of $(M, \omega)$, that is, diﬀeomorphisms $\Phi : M \to M$ such that $\Phi^∗\omega = \omega$

A vector field $X ∈ \scr X(M)$, is called symplectic if $i_X\omega$ is closed as a 1-form on M. A time-dependent vector field $X_t$ is called symplectic if $X_t$ is a symplectic vector field for all $t$

Also:
[image]

**My try:**

I have to prove that $\phi_t$ is smooth and $\phi_t^∗\omega = \omega$.
Since it is an isotopy it is already a smooth map $M \to M$ by definition so I guess I just have to prove that $\phi_t^∗\omega = \omega$.

So I tried doing this $\phi_t^*\omega(Y,Z)=\omega (\phi_t(X),\phi_t(Y))$

but it does not seem to go anywhere. Moreover it feels wrong that $\phi_t$ acts on a vector field X, when it should be acting on points of the manifold by definition, but that is what I get by definition of pullback. What is going on here?

Since $X_t$ is symplectic, $i_{X_t}\omega$ is closed, that means $d(i_{X_t}\omega)=0$. So I tried using this formula

[image]

to use the given condition and I got:

$0=d(i_{X_t}\omega)(X_t,Y)={X_t}(i_{X_t}\omega(Y))-Y(i_{X_t}\omega({X_t}))-i_{X_t}\omega([{X_t},Y])$
$={X_t}(\omega(X_t,Y))-Y(\omega(X_t,X_t))-i_{X_t}\omega({X_t},[{X_t},Y])= {X_t}(\omega(X_t,Y))-i_{X_t}\omega({X_t},[{X_t},Y])$

but I am not sure this helps

**How should I proceed?**

Answer (score 1):

Since $\phi_0=Id$, to show $\phi_t^*\omega = \omega$, we only need
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\phi_t^*\omega = 0.
$$
But this by definition is Lie derivative. So by the [Cartan formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_formula),
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}\phi_t^*\omega &= L_{X_t}\omega = (di_{X_t} + i_{X_t}d)\omega = di_{X_t}\omega + i_{X_t} d\omega = 0 + 0 = 0,
\end{align*}
since $X_t$ is a symplectic vector field and $\omega$ is a symplectic form.